# Ansible - splitting YAML-formatted list of vars across hosts.yml and group_vars

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-inventory

I have the following directory structure:

```
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts.yml
├── playbook.yml
├── group_vars
|   ├── all.yml
│   └── vm_dns.yml
└── roles
    └── pihole
        ├── handlers
        │   └── main.yml
        └── tasks
            └── main.yml
```

In `ansible.cfg` I simply have:

```
[defaults]
inventory = ./hosts.yml
```

In `group_vars/all.yml` I have some generic settings:

```
---
aptcachetime: 3600
locale: "en_GB.UTF-8"
timezone: "Europe/Paris"
```

And in `hosts.yml` I setup my PiHole VMs:

```
---
all:
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
vm_dns:
  vars:
    dns_server: true
  hosts:
    vmb-dns:
      pihole:
        dns: 
          - "185.228.168.10"
          - "185.228.169.11"
        network:
          ipv4: "192.168.2.4/24"
          interface: eth0
    vmk-dns: 
      pihole:
        dns: 
          - "185.228.168.10"
          - "185.228.169.11"
        network:
          ipv4: "192.168.3.4/24"
          interface: eth0
```

**At this point, I've not attempted to move any vars to group_vars, and everything works.**
Now, I felt could make the hosts file more readable by breaking out the settings that are the same for *all* `vm_dns` hosts to  a group_vars file. So I removed all the `dns` and `interface` lines from `hosts.yml`, and put them in a
`group_vars/vm_dns.yml` file, like this:

```
---
pihole:
  dns: 
    - "185.228.168.10"
    - "185.228.169.11"
  network:
    interface: eth0
```

At this point, the `hosts.yml` thus contains:

```
---
all:
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
vm_dns:
  vars:
    dns_server: true
  hosts:
    vmb-dns:
      pihole:
        network:
          ipv4: "192.168.2.4/24"
    vmk-dns: 
      pihole:
        network:
          ipv4: "192.168.3.4/24"
```

But when I now run the playbook, once it tries to execute a task that uses one of the vars that were moved from `hosts.yml` to `group_vars/vm_dns.yml`, Ansible fails with `AnsibleUndefinedVariable: dict object has no attribute ...`.

I'm not really sure if I'm simply misunderstanding the "Ansible way", or if what I'm trying to do (essentially having different parts of the same list split across `hosts` and `group_vars`, I suppose) is not just doable. I thought the ["flattening" that Ansible does](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#how-variables-are-merged) was supposed to handle this, but it seems Ansible is not incorporating the vars defined in `group_vars/vm_dns.yml` at all.

I've read the docs on [the subject](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#assigning-a-variable-to-many-machines-group-variables), and found some [almost-related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41818280/ansible-using-nested-groups-with-vars) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56512970/ansible-access-same-group-vars-different-children-host-groups?rq=1), but found none demonstrating YAML-formatted lists used across hosts and group_vars in this manner.

Edit: other SO or Github issues that are actually related to this question
[In Ansible, how to combine variables from separate files into one array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554415/in-ansible-how-to-combine-variables-from-separate-files-into-one-array)
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/58120
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-hash-behaviour

Comment: Can you show the part of your playbook where you are accessing the group_vars?

Comment: From your question, I suspect you did not remove the `pihole:` line in your inventory file. In which case an empty `pihole` var is declared as a host var, which will win precedence over the group var. If I remove that line I cannot reproduce your issue. This the default in ansible: replace a dict var by order of precedence. You can eventually change this behaviour by playing with the `hash_behavior=merge` parameter in `ansible.cfg`

Comment: @Zeitounator your suspicion is correct. I've edited my question to explicitly show how the hosts file looks after the changes. Your suggestion to look into `hash_behavior=merge` was also right on the money. If you want to write a short answer in line of your comment, I'll accept it.
Now that I know what to look for, I've found a few posts discussing pros and cons, including a caution against it in the Ansible docs. 
I tested it, and it makes my playbook behave just like I wanted. I'll do some more testing and researching of this issue, but for now I'm happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are keeping a definition for the `pihole` var in your inventory at host level, this one wins the game by default and replaces the previous definition at group level. See the [variable precedence documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). So if you later try to access e.g. `pihole.dns` or `pihole.network.interface`, the mappings do not exist anymore and ansible fires the above error.

This is the default behavior in ansible: replacing a previous variable by the latest by order of precedence. But you can change this behavior for dicts by setting [`hash_behaviour=merge`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-hash-behaviour) in `ansible.cfg`.

My personal experimentation with this settings where not really satisfactory: it behaved correctly with my own playbooks/roles that where made specifically for this but started to fire hard to trace bugs when including third party contributions (playbook snippets, roles, custom modules....). So I definitely don't recommend it. Moreover, this configuration has been [deprecated in ansible 2.10](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.10/changelogs/CHANGELOG-v2.10.rst#deprecated-features) and will therefore be removed in ansible 2.14. If you still want to use it, you should limit the scope of the setting as narrow as possible and certainly not set it on a global level (i.e. surely not in `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`)

What I globally use nowadays to solve this kind of problems:

1. define your variable for each host/group/whatever containing only the specific information. In your case for you host

   ```yaml
   ---
   pihole_host:
     network:
       ipv4: "192.168.2.4/24"
   ```
2. define somewhere the defaults for those settings. In your case for your group.

   ```yaml
   ---
   pihole_defaults:
     dns: 
       - "185.228.168.10"
       - "185.228.169.11"
     network:
       interface: eth0
   ```

   (Note that you can define those defaults at different level taking advantage of the above order of precedence for vars)
3. at a global level (I generally put this in `group_vars/all.yml`), define your var which will be the combination of default and specific, making sure it always defaults to empty

   ```yaml
   ---
   # Calculate pihole from group defaults and host specific
   pihole: >-
     {{
       (pihole_defaults | default({}))
       | combine((pihole_host | default({})), recursive=true)
     }}
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the worked-out example, that is very helpful!
PS.  
I just found that the [hash merge behaviour will be deprecated](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.10/changelogs/CHANGELOG-v2.10.rst#deprecated-features).

Comment: Thanks for that, I edited my answer to include the info. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked well. FYI there is a typo in the template 

`(pihole_host | default({}),`

There should be a second closing parenthesis before the comma, like this: `(pihole_host | default({})),`

Comment: @nomer I fixed it but for your information, anyone can edit any post on SO so you are strongly encouraged to fix those kind of typos yourself when you find one.